# CM12 for Htc desire 610 at&t?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, htc

I have been looking for a download for a long time, and couldn't find one. I know this is a pretty little known phone, but I still want it. Are there any devs willing to port CM12 on to this phone? I am willing to flash a custom kernel, and do pretty much whatever it takes, aside from hardware mods.

Comment: Is there any reason why this question was bad? If so, please comment. I'm a noob and still learning the ropes.

Comment: I can only speculate the reason for downvote: it's not really clear what you want. Saying "Is there any way I can get CM12 on this phone" but then  saying "looking for a download" makes it look like you either want us to find the ROM, or give you instructions for it. In any case, note that any question asking us to find off-site resources are off-topic. However, we have a consolidated guide which may help you out. See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152). Other than that, I recommend purging everything except the issue.

Comment: Detail us your research and tell us what exactly do you want now, though remaining on-topic of course. See [help/on-topic] to know more about on/off-topic content.

Comment: Thanks, I looked on most of those resources and couldn't find anything. Will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this very moment there is no cyanogenmod 12 available for your device. One developer tried to port it but it didn't boot up. The project seems to be dead.

**What you can do and what has already been done a few times:**

Visit the xda forum for your specific device and create a thread where you can ask devs for building cyanogenmod. Find other users and create a bounty. Make the device interesting for a developer and someone might pick it up and create cyanogenmod. But keep in mind that you would have to donate a small amount of money to the developer. If you can find enough people then that will be no problem.

Sorry that there is nothing much you can do.

Comment: Could I have a link to the first project?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-610/development/ported-cm-12-htc-desire-610-t3128170

Answer (score 0):

Google's `site:` & `similar:` searches will help you in finding this; took me less than an hour to find [CM12 un-official](http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-610/development/ported-cm-12-htc-desire-610-t3128170) port and [Android 4.4.4 slim ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-610/development/rom-slim-a3ul-4-4-4-build-9-0-t3149308) just by searching your titled question (minus the at&t part) like so `CM12 for Htc desire 610 site:forum.xda-developers.com`

In fact it took me longer to writw this than to find the above links and others that I read though and didn't think worth sharing.

If you check CM's wiki you'll find instructions on how to compile CM7 for your device as well as auto-generated instructions on how to port other versions of CM to a device. By using the search tips above on the parts of compiling process that you've question on you'll be able to try it yourself. For example if you don't know how to compile a kernal then try `how to compile kernel for <device name> similar:wiki.cyanogenmod.org/` and you'll find others that have tried and the steps they took.

I'd advise that you first try compiling the most stable version of CM for your device. Then once you know you can repeat the steps required for a working version start investigation of how it differs from the version you want ported and the unstable version already available. Looking at your devices' specs I see no emediat reason why you couln't have a better version it just hasn't been done yet because no one hasn't taken the steps required.
By taking your device and education into your own hands and under your own control you may find that it is very rewarding to solve things yourself. Lastly don't get to fixated on CM's ROMs there are ways to combine working bits and pieces from other ROMs into something that is your own.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by compiling and kernel, and stuff like that. Side note, when android p comes out, I hope they call it popcorn so that we can make a kernel joke.